# How do i move data from one column to another in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to move my data from the column "demographic.education" into "demographic.school".  How could i do this?

For example:

```
db.users.update({"demographic.education":{$exists: true, $ne: ""}}, {$set: {"demographic.school":demographic.education}})
```

Comment: Do you mean copy the values (leaving the `demographic.education` as is) or rename the key?

Comment: rename the key. But what would it look like if I wanted to copy the values too?

Comment: That's not as easy.  Basically you have to iterate over the collection and modify each document one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$rename` modifier for this:

```
db.users.update({"demographic.education": {$exists: true, $ne: ""}}, {$rename: {"demographic.education": "demographic.school"}})
```

[Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/)

Comment: What would it look like if I wanted to copy the values, instead of a rename? Just for future use.